# What is the best alternative for Cassandra Materialized View ? Since it is marked as not recommended for production

Tags: cassandra

If maintaining multiple table is only option according to the queries. Then how to ensure the data consistency between tables? using LoggedBatch ?? will it not affect the performance?

Also what happens/recommended practice if i need to create a new table based on the existing table? say, i have following 3 fields in cassandra table,
ID, NAME, EMAIL

I have already 2 tables with 100s of data with primary key as ID, EMAIL

Now i need another table based on NAME to serve other query